# Error installing firebase using npm after wiping disk

Tags: node.js, firebase

I just recently wiped my laptop and I'm reinstalling firebase on one of my projects but now I'm getting this error

```
../ext/call.cc:104:53: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    Local<String> current_key(Nan::To<String>(keys->Get(i)).ToLocalChecked());
                                              ~~~~~~^~~
/Users/timothyhsu/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/timothyhsu/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
../ext/call.cc:681:27: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    if (!op->ParseOp(obj->Get(type), &ops[i])) {
                     ~~~~~^~~
/Users/timothyhsu/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/timothyhsu/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.5.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
```

Does anyone know if this is some kind of incompatibility issue? I didn't have a problem installing it before using `npm install --save firebase` but now I'm coming across this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my Node version and NPM version. I reverted to an older version and the errors went away. Seems like if you use the latest Node/NPM it isn't completely supported by Firebase yet

Answer (score 0):

When moving versions you could first try a refresh which may help.

- npm cache clean --force
- delete the node_modules folder
- delete the package-lock.json file
- npm install

and try then again npm install --save firebase

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid that's all I can suggest tbh. Perhaps if you post up your ng versions etc... it might show something.

Answer (score 0):

My node version is **14.15.1**.

I did face the same error.As in the accepted answer, the issue was due to the version compatibilities between node and firebase.

But instead of downgrading my node version, I have set the below libraries to latest versions.

```
"firebase": "7.24.0",
"firebase-admin": "9.3.0",
```

And it got compiled successfully and the app ran without any issues